# style cop + resharper control comments

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

this may seem like a trivial question but when i installed the stylecop plugin for resharper my comments are getting formatted like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the gift item.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uid">
/// The uid.
/// </param>
/// <param name="upc">
/// The upc.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// </returns>
Gift GetGift(long uid, string upc);
```

as opposed to

```
/// <summary>Gets the gift item.</summary>
/// <param name="uid">The uid.</param>
/// <param name="upc">The upc.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
Gift GetGift(long uid, string upc);
```

I can't seem to find any way to turn this type of formatting off.

Answer (score 20):

If you have the Microsoft Stylecop for Resharper plugin installed in Resharper, Go to Resharper Options, Tools, then StyleCop for Resharper.  There you should see a checkbox for Use single lines for declaration headers.

Comment: I still have this described problem but - "StyleCop for ReSharper has now merged with StyleCop" https://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can install the plug-in for SyleCop from the Extension Manager from the ReSharper menu in Visual Studio. You can then manage the StyleCop Settings from Reharper-Options-Tools-StyleCop.

Answer (score 1):

Give [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) a try. This free Visual Studio extension generates even nicer XML doc comments. `param` and `return` tags are inlined whereas `summary` tags remain on separate lines. Perhaps this already suits Your needs.

Comment: i have ghost doc already, but seems that stylecop reformats the comments

Answer (score -1):

You can make GhostDoc work if you turn off "Reformat embedded XML doc comments" in your default Code Cleanup settings under the "C#" category.  Then under StyleCop section, turn off rule "1611: Element Parameters Must Be Documented" and rule "1618: Generic Type Parameters Must Be Documented".  That way code-cleanup won't re-mangle your GhostDoc comments.  Bear in mind that Code Cleanup options are solution-specific.